# Returning index with value while using each_with_index method

Tags: ruby

Constructing a basic address book in Ruby.  I have the following line of code in my program that iterates over the existing array(@address_book) based on a standard numeric input (entrynumber) to match the array index.  The resulting value that matches that index is then returned.  Here's the code in question:

```
     puts @address_book.entries.each_with_index.select {|val, i| i == (entrynumber - 1)}
```

the results look great except that the index is also returned at the bottom, like this:  (note 0 at the end of return)  I'd ideally like the index number itself at the bottom not returned.

```
View by Entry Number
Entry Number: 1
You picked 1
Name: adam adams
Phone Number: 111-111-1111
Email: aa@aa.com
0
```

What am I missing in terms of returning the value, but without the index?

Comment: Can you share to_s method of address_book class

Comment: Is it not just `@address_book.entries[entrynumber-1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

The trouble is that each_with_index is turning `@address_book.entries` into an array of arrays.  Here's an example of what I mean:

```
["a", "b"].each_with_index.to_a
# => [["a", 0], ["b", 1]]
```

So when you apply `select` to `each_with_index`, the selected elements are each going to be an array with the element and its index:

```
["a", "b"].each_with_index.select { |e, i| i == 1 }
=> [["b", 1]]
```

## A bad fix

You could fix that by using #map to select only the first element of each selected row:

```
["a", "b"].each_with_index.select { |e, i| i == 1 }.map(&:first)
 => ["b"]
```

## Using select.with_index

Better still, you could use select.with_index:

```
["a", "b"].select.with_index { |e, i| i == 1}
 => ["b"]
```

Or, in the case of your code:

```
@address_book.entries.
  each_with_index.select.with_index {|val, i| i == (entrynumber - 1)}
```

## Using Array#[]

If `@address_book.entries` is an array, then you can [index the array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D), not using select at all:

```
@address_book_entries[entrynumber - 1]
```

If it's not an array, you can turn it into one with #to_a:

```
@address_book.entries.to_a[entrynumber - 1]
```

However, if @address_book.entries is large, this could use a lot of memory.  Be careful when turning an enumeration into an array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want it to get a single item which isn't really what `select` is best suited for (especially when you're retrieving it via an index. I would probably do something like:

```
@address_book.entries.to_a[entrynumber - 1]
```